# Is it possible to serialize property attributes to XML attributes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Background:  This question is about logging the change tracking of a POCO class in C# .NET 4.0.

Let's say I have a Person class with a Name (string) property.  That Name property has a custom Attribute called [IsDirty(true/false)] that is set dynamically by a property-auditing class.

```
[IsDirty(true)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

After the changes are detected and the attributes are set, I'm storing the object via normal XML Serialization in a MS SQL Database (XML column type).

What I can't figure out is if it's possible to somehow serialize my custom attribute IsDirty along with it's current value - preferably as an XML attribute on the serialized XML element (Name) so that the final xml is like:

```
<Name IsDirty="true">John</Name>
```

Any ideas/info would be appreciated-

Comment: and you also want to be able to deserialize it back and have that attribute set to appropriate value too?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using attributes to store the "dirty" state. I didn't think you could do that. Can you explain how that works?

Comment: @Valentin - Yes, sorry that wasn't clear.  I would like to be able to deserialize it back to the object's original state.

Comment: @Scott - Well, it's an instance variable so I am assuming here (you know where that gets you) I can use GetCustomAttributes() to gain access (ultimately) to the individual attribute - and once I've got that I can just set my property value.  (I think)

Comment: @kman0 I thought that every time you call `GetCustomAttributes`, it creates new attributes? In which case it wouldn't be very useful for storing the state.

Comment: I did a quick test, and I confirmed that Attributes cannot store instance data in the way you described. Attributes are simply metadata that can be used by reflection, but do not persist between calls to GetCustomAttributes.  You still need to store the IsDirty state with the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to have to write your own XML serialization for this and mix in some reflection to check attribute values on properties.

There's a good guide to implementing the [`IXMLSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) interface [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ImplementIXmlSerializable.aspx). Unfortunately you will have to implement serialization of all properties in the class, but on the bright side, if you implement `IXmlSerializable` correctly, you can still use the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class.

In your serialization code, you can check the attribute value using something like this:

```
public class YourClass : IXmlSerializable
{
    [IsDirty(true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // skipped ReadXml and GetSchema interface methods for brevity

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("YourClass");

        var myType = typeof(YourClass);

        foreach(var propInfo in myType.GetProperties())
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(propInfo.Name);
            foreach(var attr in propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsDirtyAttribute), false))
            {
                var myAttr = attr as IsDirtyAttribute;
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Dirty", attr.Value ? "true" : "false");
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();       
    }
}
```

This code is untested and written from memory, so there are probably some bugs lurking around, but hopefully it'll get you on the right track.

Comment: I agree, this is probably the best approach for what he is trying to do.

Comment: @Anna - Thank you.  Custom serialization had crossed my mind, but I didn't really know where to start.  Hopefully I can do it both ways and even deserialize it too.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible by manually reading your Attribute and its value. You could do this by wrapping the serialization and deserialization in methods that appended/read the to/from the xml and the attribute..

However I would inherit these classes from a base class that had the property IsDirty then you neednt worry!

Comment: well it depends on definition of "neednt worry" , if they got AOP doing a lot of messy work and entities still have fields of normal types ( not all inherit from PossiblyDirty or are PossiblyDirty<T> instances) fixing serialization problem sounds like a better approach.